Minecraft server using ngrok for port forwarding stopped working
So I built a PC using pieces I had laying around to make into a Minecraft server. I installed Ubuntu on it (I think it's the latest version because I installed it like a week ago. I didn't manage to setup port forwarding on my router so my friend told me to use ngrok instead since when he did it he also didn't know how to manage port forwarding.
I launched both the server and ngrok on the same computer and it worked for a few days. A few hours ago my friend disconnected to change his skin. I don't think it has anything to do with him changing his skin but he tried reconnecting it wouldn't let him. I stopped the server and opened it again. Didn't work.
Next I closed the computer the server and ngrok are running on and launched them again. Next I tried connecting using the ngrok IP but couldn't I can connect using the one that looks like this 012.345.6.789 but I can't connect using 0.tcp.ngrok.io:12345 and my friend can't either. It worked for a few days and now it won't and I don’t know why. I get two errors when trying to connect the first one is Failed to connect to the server Disconnected.
The second only happen if I spam connections and it is internal exception java.net.socketexception connection reset. I have tried relaunching the ngrok a few times to no avail. The command I use to launch the server is java -Xmx6G -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.20.6.jar nogui then I use screen to let it run in background and launch ngrok also using screen. The command I use for ngrok is ngrok tcp 25565 (for the default port for minecraft server). Also in my server.properties the server port is set to 25565.
I don’t know if this may cause it but I set a static IP once and I think I used the same ip as the server. Also I tried port forwarding and I set a rule for port forwarding to port 25565 I think. Should I remove this rule since ngrok should open the port? Remove the static IP? What should I do?
I didn't reset my router yet since a lot of people are dependent on the internet here. I really don't understand why it won't work since it worked for a few days and I can still connect just not with ngrok
edit: I just tried re downloading everything and it still won't work. I re downloaded Ubuntu and started from scratch but I still have the same error.
I followed this video tutorial with the exception of the sudo ufw allow OpenSSH command which I replaced with sudo ufw allow ssh. I then installed ngrok and opened it on port 25565

Why are you resubmitting a question that was deleted by the community?

It was deleted on StackOverflow and somebody suggested I post it here
